# Riley Riddle #13: Under Pressure

Tags: riddle

> A line dance was inspired by my end's time in grass
>   My beginning is not quite a gas
>   My middle can help prevent falling suddenly prone
>   Make sure your pets leave me alone

Hint 1:

> This riddle is holiday-related.

Comment: When I instantly think "mushroom" - and I see that it doesn't fit all of the requirements - am I remotely close? I only say this because of the riddles title, line 4, and line 1 to a degree.

Comment: Is the prefix smoke?

Comment: Neither of ya are close

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knowing it was Holiday themed help a lot.  I'm pretty sure you are:

> Mistletoe

A line dance was inspired by my end's time in grass

> "The grass between my **toe**s" is the name of a line-dance

My beginning is not quite a gas

> **Mist**

My middle can help prevent falling suddenly prone

> **islet** is a distinct portion of tissue in the body.   (I realize this omits a 't' but I can't find anything else)

Make sure your pets leave me alone

> Mistletoe is Poisonous to pets